# How to access Principal of WebSocket that was set in a ChannelInterceptor? Principal is null

Tags: java, websocket, spring-security

I'm trying to get the Principal from the SimpMessageHeaderAccessor in my @MessageMapping annotated method.

The Principal is being set with a ChannelInterceptor on connection.

Even though when I console.log the connection frames and see the "user-name" header, the Principal is always null in my @MessageMapping method.

Thanks for any advice :)

MessageController class:

```
@Controller
public class MessageController {

    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    public MessageController(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/private")
    public void message(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor accessor, @Payload Message message){
        System.out.println(accessor.getUser().getName());
    }

}
```

ChannelInterceptor class:

```
@Service
public class CustomHandshakeInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {

    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    public CustomHandshakeInterceptor(JwtUtil jwtUtil) {
        this.jwtUtil = jwtUtil;
    }

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
        if(StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())){
            Object raw = message.getHeaders().get(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.NATIVE_HEADERS);
            if(raw instanceof Map){
                Object token = ((Map) raw).get("JWT_TOKEN");
                if(token instanceof ArrayList){
                    System.out.println(((ArrayList<?>) token).get(0).toString());
                    accessor.setUser(new Principal() {
                        @Override
                        public String getName() {
                            return jwtUtil.extractUsername(((ArrayList<?>) token).get(0).toString());
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            System.out.println("FROM INTERCEPTOR " + accessor.getUser().getName());
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

SocketConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class SocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    private CustomHandshakeInterceptor handshakeInterceptor;

    public SocketConfig(CustomHandshakeInterceptor handshakeInterceptor) {
        this.handshakeInterceptor = handshakeInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/stomp")
                .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("queue");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/users");
    }


    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(handshakeInterceptor);
    }
}
```

Client console:

```
Frame
body: ""
command: "CONNECTED"
headers: {user-name: 'david', heart-beat: '0,0', version: '1.1'}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Error Message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.security.Principal.getName()" because the return value of "org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.getUser()" is null
    at eu.filip.backend.socket.MessageController.message(MessageController.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: What is "MessageController.java:28"?

Comment: have you tried injecting the principal into the function instead

Comment: @cliff2310 MessageController.java:28 is the line where i print the accessor.getUser().getName().

Comment: @Toerktumlare Yes I have, the Principal is still null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking things up on YouTube and Google i found the `DefaultHandshakeHandler` Class which has the `determineUser` method that returns a Principal. I basically made my own implementation of the Principal assignment and added it via the SocketConfig `registerStompEndpoints.setHandshakeHandler()` method.

After doing that I was able to retrieve my Principal in the `@MessageMapping` annotated method!